# NSArrayController selection

Tags: core-data, nsarraycontroller, nspopupbutton

I want to achieve the following:
There is a list of persons (name, birthday, photo)
I want to select a person name in the NSPopUpButton and show
other details below.

How can I do it using bindings only?

I use NSArrayController to populate NSPopUpButton.
I use NSArrayController.selection. to populate birthday and photo fields.
But when I select a name in NSPopUpButton selection property of the NSArrayController 
not changed.

In other words how can I get an object (NSManagedObject) selected in NSPopUpButton of change selection property of the NSArrayController using bindings only.

Thanks,
Vlad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. To make it we have to bind selected index of the NSPopUpButton to the selectionIndex of a NSArrayController.